# Пользователь меняет  текст в блоке div

Tags: jquery, javascript, ui

Здравствуте, кто знает как сделать так чтобы пользователь мог в определенном div поменять текс на свой. Например кликнув два раза на div появляеться возможность напечатоть свой текст.

есть такои блок

```
<div id="element-1"><div class="delete"></div><p>Текст текст текст текст текст</p></div>
```

пишу такой скрипт

```
//показываем крестик при клике на элемент
    $(".newElement").on('click', function(){
        $(this).find('.delete').fadeIn(100);
        });

          //прячим крестик при уводе мыши  
        $(".newElement").hover (function(){
            $(this).find('.delete').fadeOut(3000);
            }); 
            //удаляем элемент кликнув по крестику
        $('.newElement').on('click','.delete', function(){ $(this).parent().remove();

})  
var text = 'слова'
$('#element-1 ').on('click', function(){ $(this).text(text);

})
```

понимаю что не правельно.

Надо чтоб при двоином клике у пользователя была возможность в переменную text написать свой текст, а в div element-1 он изменился.И надо чтоб цвет текста пользователь задовал Возможноли такое?

Зарание все спасибо

Answer (score 2):

Рискну предложить более простое и быстрое решение. В HTML5 есть возможность [сделать текст редактируемым](http://html5demos.com/contenteditable):

```
<div contenteditable="true">Кликни, чтобы изменить</div>
```

Comment: А почему если даеш id диву то перестает работать?

Comment: А еще после того как элемент перетащили в другое место средствами jquery он вобще не работает.

Comment: Интересно, как вы даете диву идентификатор. [У меня работает и с ID](http://jsfiddle.net/HzuCF/). Про перетаскивание ничего тем более не могу сказать без кода. Возможно, ваш drag-'n-drop меняет значение contenteditable на false и после перетаскивания нужно передвинутому диву явно поменять значение атрибута.

Answer (score 0):

Если говорить сугубо о коде, который меняет текст, то я нашёл такое решение:

```
$('#id_вашего_дива').text('ваш_текст');
```

Также можно попробовать так:

```
document.getElementById('id_вашего_дива').text('ваш_текст');
```

По крайней мере у меня так работает. Я вешаю на событие onClick вызов функции, в которой у меня этот код прописан, и всё работает.